# Editando a cor de fundo do elemento button atrelado ao bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando alterar a cor do background de um select a partir do momento que é selecionada alguma opção. No entanto, como faço uso do bootstrap-select, existem alguns elementos extras que devem ser tratados para tornar isso possível.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
<option></option>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker">
<option></option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>


  $('select').on('change', function(){
  
    var valor_atual = $(this).val();    
    
    if (valor_atual!='') {      

    $(this).nextAll('button:first').css('background-color', '#fcffcb');
  
    }
      else {
       $(this).nextAll('button:first').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
    }
    
    
});
```

Não estou sabendo localizar o elemento "button" (que é o elemento atrelado ao select) para alterar a sua respectiva cor.

Como será que devo proceder?

Segue link do código:
http://jsfiddle.net/p5c4wvuf/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O bootstrap-select aplica display none no seu input select, e cria uma **div** com uma lista dentro, por isso fica com um layout legal... então para resolver o seu problema é só definir um id para o seu **select** e no event change você altera a cor do elemento usando **data-id**='*id do elemento select*'

```js
      $('select').on('change', function(){
      
    var wName = $(this).attr("id")
        
    $("[data-id='"+wName+"']").css('background-color', '#fcffcb');  
        
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="input1" name="input1" class="selectpicker">
<option></option>
<option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="input2" name="input2"  class="selectpicker">
<option></option>
<option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Existe um outro plugin chamado select2 https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage  acho os recursos dele bem interessante... você pode dar uma pesquisada

Comment: Nossa, genial! Muito obrigado!